# Is it necessary to implement NSCoding protocol when use NSKeyedArchiver?

Tags: ios, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

The doc says archivedDataWithRootObject

> Returns an NSData object containing the encoded form of the object graph whose root object is given.

it says encoded, but the parameter it receives is **id _Nonnull**, I think **id < NSCoding >** is more appropriate, and for now even the class doesn't implement the NSCoding protocol there is no error, how to understand the meaning of encoded form and when should I use NSCoding explicitly?

Comment: When you call `archivedDataWithRootObject:`, it sends the specified object an `encodeWithCoder:` message, which is part of `NSCoding`. However, since ObjC is a highly dynamic language, you *don't even need* to implement `NSCoding`. You can forward it to a different selector or another object altogether. Focus on the correctness of your app. Don't worry about the exact wording in the documentation or header file.

Comment: @ZoffDino so did you mean even the class doesn't implement the protocol, objc will handle the encoding automatically?

Comment: No! You have to code it manually, by either implementing `NSCoding` or use ObjC message forwarding to encode the object. ObjC will not do it for you

Comment: @ZoffDino but why I don't implement the NSCoding or forward the message it also works well..